# How can iterate rows of dataframe using index?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I am looking to apply a loop over indices of dataframe in python.

**My loop is like:**

```
for index in DataFrame:
 if index <= 10
    index= index+1
 return rows(index)
```

Comment: You can iterate over `df.index.values`. But maybe you can you explain *why* you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataFrame.iterrows()`:

```
for row, srs in pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4]}).iterrows():
    ...do something...
```

Comment: sorry to say your answer does not help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index <=10:
        print row
```

This is going to print the first 10 rows

Answer (score 0):

1. *We have to take list of index if any condition is required*
2. *we can take the rows in list of Series*

for i in index:
    l1 = list(range(i-10,i+2))
    all_index.extend(l1)

all_index = list(set(all_index))

all_series = []

## take list of series

for i in all_index:
    a = df.iloc[i, :]
    all_series = all_series.extend(a)